# Creating a simple(but not for me) db

Tags: database-design, ms-access, relational-database

I am trying to build a db to track the going-ons within a small craigslist selling operation.

Basically how the guys are operating is like so.

1. some one buys lets say 3 books at a price of $10 each.
2. They post it on CL
3. And they sell it for $20.
4. The purchaser gets his $10 back for each book sold, plus 1/3 of the profits.

The problem is they are pretty much buying same book each time, but the price they are buying it at changes. Sometimes, they buy the book for $12, at other $15. They will buy other books, if the market is good on them.

Want I'm wanting to do is  build and inventory list that tracks the books by the its name, and by the price they were purchased at.

So if we have 10 "Green Eggs and Ham" books, that cost of $10 a piece, and we have 5 "Green Egg and Ham" Books that cost $15. the inventory list should reflect two separate items.  This is so that the investor gets paid appropriately for his investment.

I am having trouble dessigning the db in this fashion. I have the following tables:

**Product**

- ID **PK**
- Name
- Description

**Inventory**

- ID
- Purchase Date
- Product_ID **PK**
- Purchase_Price **PK**
- Quantity

**Purchasing**

- ID **PK**
- Product_ID
- Product_Quanity
- Purchase_Price

My reasoning so far suggest that i should keep track of the types items they are selling, in a products table.  Also keep track of when they purchase an item, and how many they purchase of that item at a given time; hence the purchasing table.  Then I want to build a list of what i have in inventory, but each record needs to unique based on the item and its cost.  So i decided that I would use a composite Key of purchase price, and Product Id to do that.

Is it possible to use relate the purchase price, and the Product ID from the Purchasing table to my Inventory table, if the fields aren't Primary Keys?  Is my method so far appropriate for what I am trying to accomplish? Is there a better method for what I am try to do.

*there are other elements to the db that I haven't mentioned, but will if they are necessary*

Thanks to all who can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Product**

- ID **PK**
- ProductName
- Description

**Purchase**

- ID **PK**
- ProductID **FK**
- PurchDate
- Quantity
- PurchPrice

**Sale**

- ID **PK**
- ProductID **FK**
- SaleDate
- Quantity
- SalePrice

**Inventory**

```
SELECT ID, ProductName, 
       (SELECT Sum(Quantity) FROM Purchase WHERE ProductID=Product.ID) -
       (SELECT Sum(Quantity) FROM Sale WHERE ProductID=Product.ID) AS NumInStock
FROM Product
```

What the above query is doing is returning the ID and ProductName from the Product table as well as calculating the Number of that item in stock.  The first subquery `(SELECT Sum(Quantity) FROM Purchase WHERE ProductID=Product.ID)` returns the sum of all matching items that have been purchased.  It then subtracts from that total the sum of all matching items that have been sold `(SELECT Sum(Quantity) FROM Sale WHERE ProductID=Product.ID)` to come up with what is in stock.

To get the number of iPads purchased at $100, you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT Sum(Quantity) AS NumiPadsFor100
FROM Purchase WHERE PurchPrice = 100
```

To get the profit on a particular item, that would be a bit more cumbersome to do all in queries, but would be straightforward to do in code.

Comment: So i don't need an Inventory Relation? just a view of inventory is that what you are saying?

Comment: Exactly.  If you keep track of your purchases and sales then the difference is your on-hand inventory.

Comment: could you explain this sql statement, i'm fresh at this.

Comment: the problem is that i need to inventory based on how much each item cost me.  i need to be able to pull up the amount of "ipads" i purchased at a rate of $100

Comment: You don't need inventory since it's derived from the movements. You also don't need separate tables for Purchase and Sale. One table for Movements is enough, the sign of Quantity will do the trick: + for IN, - for OUT. Just SUM the movements grouped by Ref and you have your stock.

Comment: Thanks peeps.This helps a lot.

Comment: @iDevlop should i creat a table for the different types of movements?  i.e. sale, purchase

Answer (score 0):

So, Before the product goes to inventory it should be purchase right? Just use PurchasingID as a foreign key in Inventory table - this will eliminate the need of using purchase_price in both tables.
EDIT:
It will be like this:
Product
ID PK
Name
Description

Inventory
ID PK
Purchase Date
Quantity
Purchasing_ID FK

Purchasing
ID PK
Product_ID FK
Product_Quanity
Purchase_Price

You probably will need an extra table between purchasing and inventory bassed on your needs

Comment: Yea, but i am not sure how to design that other table, and how it should interact with the rest of the DB.

Answer (score 0):

1 table for Products, and 1 table for movements (sales as well as purchases). This way your inventory will be very easy. If have large volumes (let's say more than 50.000 movements a year) you may want to look at [this interesting study](http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html).